# How put Session with different database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I've two database which is 1 for system two for data and I've a select option and I want to get the session selected using Session::put() laravel but Iam getting error,

Error

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 102: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\larasimak\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
>   on line 105 and defined

this the code

```
$tahun= Session::put('tahun', DB::connection('pgsql2')->table('laporan')->get('tahun'));
$bulan=Session::put('bulan', DB::connection('pgsql2')->table('laporan')->get('bulan'));;    
$tahun2=Session::put('tahun2', DB::connection('pgsql2')->table('laporan')->get('tahun2'));;
$bulan2=Session::put('bulan2', DB::connection('pgsql2')->table('laporan')->get('bulan2'));;
$audit1 = Session::put('audit1', DB::connection('pgsql2')->table('laporan')->get('audit1'));;
$audit2 =Session::put('audit2', DB::connection('pgsql2')->table('laporan')->get('audit2'));;
```

I've read that people use Session with 2 param but still I'am getting error. how do I fix this ?

Comment: What you want to do with `get('tahun')`

Comment: @Rishi I put in the query then display it on the data table `$sql_TotalAsetLancar=DB::connection('pgsql2')->select("SELECT SUM(nilai) AS total FROM laporan WHERE tahun='$tahun' AND bulan='$bulan' AND parentgrup='10' AND (audited=$audit1)");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get()` function requires an array of column names. You are passing in a string.

`->get('tahun')` should be `->get(array('tahun'))`